# Are there any side effect with SlenderTone system abs belt?

Tags: abdominals, slendertone

I want to know if the [Slendertone belt](http://www.slendertone.com) has any negative effects on muscles or on the mind. I have read some reviews and feedback online and found nothing dangerous about it. Is it an effect device for toning up your abs?

Comment: http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704779704574553790579199098.html

Comment: It might be somewhat useful if you've got an abdominal injury you're trying to recover from, but then you should really be getting the electrical stimulation done by your physiotherapist.

Comment: The only (either good or bad) effect it has is on your budget: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/4896/5638 (the question confused TENS and EMS, but the answer is on EMS)

Comment: Side effects can include skin irritation, bruising, burns and sleep disruption. Also do NOT use if pregnant. EMS units are good for rehab in surgeries such as tendon repairs where the muscle has to start being activated again, but in general you aren't going to get the benefit without the work. When it comes to fitness/exercise, there really aren't any short cuts.

Comment: I've written an answer to a [similar question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/11431/3941).